# Problem clarification for Folland 5.33, real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

I am trying to understand a problem in folland's real analysis.

In a norm linear space.

There is no slowest rate of decay of the terms of an absolutely convergent series, that is, there is no  sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive number such that $\sum a_n |c_n| < \infty$ iff $\{c_n\}$ is bounded.

I am confused by the problem, take $\mathbb{R}$ for example, I can certainly let $\{c_n\}$ be $\{\frac{1}{n^2} \}$, and $\{a_n\}$ be $\{1\}$, then $\sum a_n |c_n| < \infty$ and $\{c_n\}$ is bounded and $\{a_n\}$ are positive, I am certainly misinterpreting the problem, but I'm not sure what I'm misinterpreting, any help with clarifying my confusion would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: You want to show that if $(a_n)_n$ is any sequence of positive numbers, then the following does *not* hold: For every sequence of real numbers $c = (c_n)_n$, we have that $c$ is bounded if and only if $\sum_n a_n |c_n|<\infty$.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was reading it as A iff B, where A is the statement 
"there is no sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive numbers such that $\sum a_n |c_n| < \infty$", and B is the statement $\{c_n\}$ is bounded. That cleared things up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sequence $a_n=1/n^2$ does not work: $\sum_{n}a_n|c_n|$ is convergent even for $c_n=\sqrt{n}$ which is not bounded.

P.S. This is an interesting [reference](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687153?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my problem was that I was reading the statement incorrecly, I was reading it as A iff B, where A is the statement 
"there is no sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive numbers such that $\sum a_n |c_n| < \infty$", and B is the statement $\{c_n\}$ is bounded, which led me to think that this is a statement about $\{c_n\}$.

Comment: I see... I edited my answer with a (hopefully) interesting reference.